# I am trying to do a basic colour conversion in python however I can't seem to get past the below error

Tags: python, opencv

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image, face = face_detector(frame)

def face_detector(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is...

Comment: can you also provide an example data?

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that you're stuck in an infinite loop.  `while True` will go on forever until you break out of it, or an exception is raised from something in the loop body.  Why? Because `True` always evaluates to `True`. Go figure.

Possible solutions:

- Explicitly break out of the loop. Somewhere, at some point inside the body of a `while True` loop, you need to have a `break` command.
- Use `while ...:` where `...` is some expression, eg `while foo < bar:`. That way, the loop will terminate when the expression evaluates `False`.
- Use a for loop instead: `for foo in foos:` where `foos` is an iterable and `foo` is the variable name assigned to each item in that iterable in turn. This way the loop naturally terminates when you run out of foos.

Which solution is best depends on what you're trying to do and what your data or state looks like. Without more information, I can't tell you which to use.